# How to get HTML value within a XML, Android

Tags: java, android, html, xml, saxparser

Hello i know this is a current problem

Take a look at this, i can't find what i'm doing wrong :

here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<item>
    <name>Margherita</name>
    <description>Single cheese topping</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <name>Double Cheese Margherita</name>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
        <span>Loaded with Extra Cheese</span><br />
        ]]>
    </description>
</item> 
</menu>
```

I need to get the Description as a String with the HTML content inside.
The first one work well, i can get the description without the `<![CDATA[`
But the second one **with** `<![CDATA[` is empty ...

Here is my code :

Adapter.java :

```
  XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

    String xml = null;
    try {
        xml = parser.readTextFile(context.getAssets().open(FILENAME));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // getting DOM element
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 
    // Extract items from DOM
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        Medoc m = new Medoc();
        // fill Medoc informations
        m.setTitle(parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        m.setDescription(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)); 
        // save in memory
        data.add(m);
    }
```

saxParser.java :

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if (elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                 if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 else if (child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)
                     return child.getNodeValue();
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

 /**
  * Getting XML String from stream
  * @param Element isteam
  * */  
 public String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return outputStream.toString();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    return child.getNodeValue();
}
```

The CDATA section is not a Text node. If you want to also lookup CDATA Sections, you should be looking for `Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE` in addition to `Node.TEXT_NODE`.